# Xcode: possible to attach user-defined attributes on controls from the designer?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'd like to attach arbitrary attributes to UIKit controls created in the editor. Is this possible? When I try, I get the infamous error:

```
NSUnknownKeyException: [<UISwitch 0x9d79140> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key hello.
```

This leads me to say no, but it'd really clean some things up if it was somehow possible.

Comment: You could do this using Objective-C associated storage: objc_setAsociatedObject / objc_getAssociatedObject.

Comment: Yeah, trying to use the designer-only for this. Infuriating that it's only for controllers.

Comment: You mean, you're trying to actually set the attributes in (the software formerly known as) Interface Builder?

Comment: That's correct. I'm doing some metaprogramming with RubyMotion and it'd be awesome to be able to describe the elements more. I'm considering hijacking the accessibility elements, but that's kind of evil.

Comment: What are the attributes? You could also associate a decorator object with each control. Or maybe better yet, subclass the UIKit class and override setValue:forKey: or setValue:forUndefinedKey:.

Comment: Just a string value. I need to hang it somewhere that I can set from the designer and also access at runtime.

Comment: I think I would either subclass the UIKit class, or use a category to implement `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` on say UIControl.

Comment: Brilliant. Please add that as an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: Great. Hope it works out! I'd be curious to see the code you end up using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try one of these approaches:

- Subclass the UIKit classes, overriding `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` or `setValue:forKey:`
- Create a category on UIControl to reimplement `setValue:forUndefinedKey:`